# How to create directory tree from a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, algorithm

I would like to write a fucntion that mimics a folder structure in Python. Given a list of strings I would like to create a tree of folders & subfolders. For example:

['beers', 'wines', 'beers/ipa/stone', 'wines/red/cabernet']

Would output a dictionary with the following:

```
    { 
        'beers': {
            'ipa': {
                'stone': {}
            } 
        },

        'wines': {
            'red': {
                'cabernet': {}
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The first two answers are different. I think they easily can give different output for more complicated input.

Answer (score 1):

Just go through you list and add names of each strings that you split on the slash character.  You can use setdefault() to ensure that the next level dictionary exist (i.e. auto create entries as you go)

```
strings = ['beers', 'wines', 'beers/ipa/stone', 'wines/red/cabernet']
directory = dict()
for path in strings:
    d = directory
    for name in path.split("/"):
        d = d.setdefault(name,dict())
print(directory)

{'beers':
    { 'ipa': {'stone': {}} },
 'wines': 
    {'red':  {'cabernet': {}} }
}
```

*With Python 3, the order of items in each dict will correspond to their original relative order in the list of strings*

If you want the items in each dictionary to appear in alphanumerical order, you can change the loop like this:

```
directory = dict()
for path in sorted(s.split("/") for s in strings):
    d = directory
    for name in path:
        d = d.setdefault(name,dict())
```

If you like recursive functions, here's a simple one that does the same thing (but less efficiently):

```
def makeTree(strings, separator="/", tree=None):
    tree = tree or dict()
    for name,*subs in (s.split(separator,1) for s in strings):
        tree[name] = makeTree(subs, separator, tree.get(name))
    return tree

d = makeTree(strings)
print(d)

{'beers':
    { 'ipa': {'stone': {}} },
 'wines': 
    {'red':  {'cabernet': {}} }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
x = ['beers', 'wines', 'beers/ipa/stone', 'wines/red/cabernet']

def add_items(d, items):
    if len(items) == 1:
        if items[0] in d:
            return
        else:
            d[items[0]] = dict()
    else:
        if items[0] not in d:
            d[items[0]] = dict()
        add_items(d[items[0]], items[1:])

out = dict()
for item in x:
    items = item.split("/")
    add_items(out, items)
print(out)

{'wines': {'red': {'cabernet': {}}}, 'beers': {'ipa': {'stone': {}}}}
```